# Probability Distribution given a CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have been looking all over for the past hour trying to figure out how to solve this problem. It really is frustrating. It seems kind of trivial but I can not find a single resource to help me solve this (including my text book and professor's slides).

Let X be a random variable with cdf:

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} 0& x < -2 \\1/8 & -2 \le x < -1 \\3/8& -1 \le x < 0 \\5/8& 0\le x < 2\\ 7/8& 1 \le x < 2 \\1& x >= 2\end{cases}$$

I need to find the probability distribution for X in order to answer the subsequent problems, but I do not know how! Any help is appreciated, thank you

edit: i tried to guess and check it, for $-2 <= x < -1$, it is $P(-2) - P(-3) = 1/8$, so I guess $P(-2) = 1/8$, but as I do this for the others, the numbers don't work out right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check that it is a probability **mass** function . since the CDF is not continiuos. And your required pmf. 
$$P(X=-2)=1/8\\P(X=-1)=2/8\\P(X=0)=2/8\\P(X=1)=2/8\\P(X=2)=1/8$$

Figure out yourself how I got these values.

Comment: Now I really do not understand. I had thought 1<= x < 2 = P(1) - P(0) = 2/8 - 2/8 = 0??

Comment: @ricefieldboy You got it right?

Comment: Yes, I see. You subtract value from the value before for x. Thank you